# C# event start looping

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

I have litle problem with event in `MVP` view and presenter.
When `_artistToolbarButton_Click`event is fired he start show me another registred events. Why does this happen? Check animation and you will see antoher message box from another event is also fired!

[image]

Here is my form code:

**Form:**

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainView
    {
        #region Properties

        public IPresenter Presenter { get; set; }

        #endregion

        // Constructor
        public MainForm()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Presenter = new MainPresenter(this);
            this.WireEvents();
        }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnLoad;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ShowArtist;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ShowLibrary;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ShowTopList;

        // Wire events
        private void WireEvents()
        {
            this.Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
            this._artistToolbarButton.Click += new EventHandler(_artistToolbarButton_Click);
            this._libraryToolbarButton.Click += new EventHandler(_libraryToolbarButton_Click);
            this._topListToolbarButton.Click += new EventHandler(_topListToolbarButton_Click);
        }

        #region Events
        // Load
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.OnLoad != null)
            {
                this.OnLoad(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        // Artist
        private void _artistToolbarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ShowArtist != null)
            {
                this.ShowArtist(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        // Library
        private void _libraryToolbarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ShowLibrary != null)
            {
                this.ShowLibrary(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        // Top list
        private void _topListToolbarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ShowTopList != null)
            {
                this.ShowTopList(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

   public class MainPresenter : IPresenter
    {
        private IMainView _view;

        // Constructor
        public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
        {
            this._view = view;
            this.WireEvents();
        }

        // Wire events
        public void WireEvents()
        {
            this._view.OnLoad += OnLoad;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowArtist;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowLibrary;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowTopList;
        }

        // On load
        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OnLoad");
        }

        // ShowArtist
        private void ShowArtist(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowArtist");
        }

        // ShowLibrary
        private void ShowLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowLibrary");
        }

        //ShowTopList
        private void ShowTopList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowTopList");
        }
    }
```

**Presenter:**

```
   public class MainPresenter : IPresenter
    {
        private IMainView _view;

        // Constructor
        public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
        {
            this._view = view;
            this.WireEvents();
        }

        // Wire events
        public void WireEvents()
        {
            this._view.OnLoad += OnLoad;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowArtist;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowLibrary;
            this._view.ShowArtist += ShowTopList;
        }

        // On load
        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OnLoad");
        }

        // ShowArtist
        private void ShowArtist(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowArtist");
        }

        // ShowLibrary
        private void ShowLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowLibrary");
        }

        //ShowTopList
        private void ShowTopList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ShowTopList");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks to be a simple copy and paste error in `WireEvents`

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete and verifyable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), don´t let user here search your entire code. Try to narrow your problem down to the absolute minimum which is needed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code into this one:

```
// Wire events
public void WireEvents()
{
    this._view.OnLoad += OnLoad;
    this._view.ShowArtist += ShowArtist;
    this._view.ShowLibrary += ShowLibrary;
    this._view.ShowTopList += ShowTopList;
}
```

It's simply a event link error :)

Answer (score 1):

You should properly subscribe to events in **Presenter**:

```
public void WireEvents()
{
    this._view.OnLoad += OnLoad;
    this._view.ShowArtist += ShowArtist;  // this._view.ShowArtist
    this._view.ShowLibrary += ShowLibrary; // this._view.ShowArtist
    this._view.ShowTopList += ShowTopList; // this._view.ShowArtist
}
```